# Regex to fix bad deliminators at start of filenames

Tags: regex

I've been trying to write a regex to correct bad deliminators after the authors name in ebook file names. Using File Renamer in Javascript.

This is what I have so far:

[DEMO HERE](http://regex101.com/r/kX9tQ2/1)

```
^(.*?)\b(- | --| -- |-- | -)\b
```

The first deliminator in every file name should be " - " These are the types I'm attempting to correct:

```
Author Name -Series 00 -Title.txt
Author_Name --Series 01 -Title -Genre.txt
File_Name1-- Sometext- more-info (V1.0).txt
Joe Bloggs- Blah
David Cay-Johnston -- Free Lunch.rtf
```

--------------DO NOT MATCH-------------

```
Jackie S. Newton-Paines - Blah- The Biography.epub
Fred Bloggs - Series - title.txt
```

If I change the regex to:

```
^(.*?)\b(- | --| -- |-- | -| - )\b
```

with the REPLACE:

```
"$1 - "
```

Then it works but doesn't allow me to see what changes are going to be made in the preview, because it changes every " - " to " - ". (I use the replace "!$1 - " and then sort on preview to see what changes are to be made before applying)

Is there a way to stop the regex matching " - " and anything after, so I can preview the changes?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you don't want your prefix `(.*?)` to contain the string `-` - right?

Well, you can ensure that this is the case by failing to match the "any character" `.` that is at the start of the string `-` using a negative lookahead.  Specifically, replace `(.*?)` with `((?! - ).)*?`.

Your complete regex should then be: `^(((?! - ).)*?)\b(- | --| -- |-- | -)\b`

Comment: Thank you Eamon. I had to change it slightly as it was only matching the last letter of each name so the substitution was messed up, but this works OK: (^((?! - ).)*?)\b(- | --| -- |-- | -)\b

Comment: @Zarnia that's odd, because that regex is exactly equivalent.  The `^` should mean that the match *must* start at the beginning of the string/line so a substring that's not at the beginning (like one including only the last letter) really shouldn't work (and it works as intended in my testing). Are you sure you didn't just miss the `^` when copy&pasting?

Comment: Check it out, here's yours: http://regex101.com/r/oZ0xI9/1 Here's my version: http://regex101.com/r/eZ6zV7/1

Comment: ahh, it's the capture, not the match - fixed, thanks!